# How to display info if a tag value is X

Tags: php, xml

I would like to know how can I display na INFO from XML if the value of a tag is CANFONTI.

So, I have na updated XML page: http://www.cidadehoje.pt/musics/musics/te.xml

Snippet:

```
<onairplaylist radio="RADIO CIDADE HOJE">
    <element>
        <author>DOISMILEOITO</author>
        <title>SÓ FAÇO BEM (2011)</title>
        <genre>POP</genre>
        <table>CANFONTI</table>
        <id>0019826001</id>
    </element>
    <element>
        <author>Anotherguy</author>
        <title>Let's play another song</title>
        <genre>FOO</genre>
        <table>BAR</table>
        <id>9999999991</id>
    </element>
</onairplaylist>
```

And this code:

```
<?php
$x = simplexml_load_file('http://www.cidadehoje.pt/musics/musics/te.xml');
echo '<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Raleway-light" size="+3" style="display:inline">';
echo $x->element[0]->author[0];
echo ' - ';
echo $x->element[0]->title[0];
echo '</font>';
?>
```

I just want to show "author - title" if the tag "table" have the value "CANFONTI".

Can you help me with this?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean something like this:

```
<?php
$x = simplexml_load_file('http://www.cidadehoje.pt/musics/musics/te.xml');
if($x->element[0]->table[0] == "CANFONTI")
{
    echo '<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Raleway-light" size="+3" style="display:inline">';
    echo $x->element[0]->tag[0];
    echo ' - ';
    echo $x->element[0]->title[0];
    echo '</font>';
}
?>
```

you should read some book about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xpath()` to select all desired elements:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // $x containing the XML
$elements = $xml->xpath("//element[table = 'CANFONTI']");
```

Now output:

```
foreach ($elements as $element) echo $element->title . PHP_EOL;
```

See it running: https://eval.in/220617

line 2 will select all `<element>` with `<title>' being 'CANFONTI` and store those in array `$elements`. Then loop and echo.